# Slider seekbar drag function for the audio player on website

Tags: javascript, html, audio, draggable

Yesterday, somebody very helpful converted the code for me into one that works fine but I'd like to format this code so that it has a draggable function. More specifically, I have a seekbar and to rewind a song I have to click on this seekbar and I can't drag it (you click and drag). I would like to add such a feature so that I can drag to scroll through the song. I have no idea what to do. :/ Here's code.

```
var audio = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
var playBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.play');
var seekBar = document.querySelectorAll('.seek-bar');
var fillBar = document.querySelectorAll('.fill');
var pointerdown = false;
var playing = undefined;

function getP(e, i) {
  var p = (e.clientX - seekBar[i].offsetLeft) / seekBar[i].clientWidth;
  p = clamp(0, p, 1);
  return p;
}

function clamp(min, val, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(min, val), max);
}

function updateFillBar(i, val) {
  fillBar[i].style.width = val + '%';
}

function handleTimeline(i) {
  if (pointerdown) return;
  var p = audio[i].currentTime / audio[i].duration;
  updateFillBar(i, p * 100);
}

function resetAudio(i) {
  audio[i].currentTime = 0;
  updateFillBar(i, 0);
}

function handleSeekbar(e, i) {
  pointerdown = true;
  var vidDur = audio[i].duration;
  var seekCoords = Math.round(
    (e.clientX - seekBar[i].offsetLeft) *
      (vidDur / seekBar[i].clientWidth)
  );
  handleAudioPlayback(i, seekCoords);
  var p = getP(e, i);
  updateFillBar(i, p * 100);
}

function handleButtonClick(i, time) {
  if (playing === undefined) {
    playing = i;
  }
  handleAudioPlayback(i, time);
}

function handleAudioPlayback(i, time) {
  if (playing !== i) {
    audio[playing].pause();
    playing = i;
  }
  var a = audio[i];
  if (pointerdown) {
    a.currentTime = time;
    a.play();
    pointerdown = false;
  } else if (a.paused) {
    a.play();
  } else {
    a.pause();
  }
}

audio.forEach((node, i) => {
  node.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
    handleTimeline(i);
  });
  node.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    resetAudio(i);
  });
  seekBar[i].addEventListener(
    'pointerdown',
    function(e) {
      handleSeekbar(e, i);
    },
    false
  );
  playBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    handleButtonClick(i, 0);
  });
});
```

```
<div class="audio-player">
  <audio src="https://milessite.com/music/music.mp3"></audio>
  <button class="play">play</button>
  <div class="seek-bar">
    <div class="fill"><div class="handle"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="audio-player">
  <audio src="https://milessite.com/music/music1.mp3"></audio>
  <button class="play">play</button>
  <div class="seek-bar">
    <div class="fill"><div class="handle"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #0f0f0f;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  touch-action: none;
}
.audio-player {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.play {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
.play:focus {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
.seek-bar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.fill {
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.handle {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
.seek-bar:hover .handle {
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's going to make much more sense to use an HTML range slider. The below simplifies your code quite a bit as well.

```js
var audio = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
var playBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.play');
var seekBar = document.querySelectorAll('.seek-bar');
var fillBar = document.querySelectorAll('.fill');
var seek = document.querySelectorAll('.seek');
var seeking = false;
var playing = undefined;

function updateProgress(i) {
  var duration = audio[i].duration;
  var multiplier = 100 / duration;
  var currentTime = audio[i].currentTime;
  seek[i].value = currentTime * multiplier;
}

function resetAudio(i) {
  audio[i].currentTime = 0;
  updateProgress(i, 0);
}

function handleSeek(e, i) {
  seeking = true;
  var seekPosition = e.target.value / 100;
  var playFrom = audio[i].duration * seekPosition;
  handleAudioPlayback(i, playFrom);
  updateProgress(i);
}

function handleButtonClick(i, time) {
  if (playing === undefined) {
    playing = i;
  }
  handleAudioPlayback(i, time);
}

function handleAudioPlayback(i, time) {
  var seekPosition = seek[i].value;
  if (playing !== i && !seeking) {
    audio[playing].pause();
    playing = i;
  }
  var a = audio[i];
  if (seeking) {
    a.currentTime = time;
    seeking = false;
  } else if (a.paused) {
    a.play();
  } else {
    a.pause();
  }
}

audio.forEach((node, i) => {
  node.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
    updateProgress(i);
  });
  node.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    resetAudio(i);
  });
  playBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    handleButtonClick(i, 0);
  });
  seek[i].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    handleSeek(e, i);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #0f0f0f;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  touch-action: none;
}
.audio-player {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.play {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
.play:focus {
  background-color: #f90;
}
input[type='range'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}
input[type='range']:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #434343;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 16px;
  background: #666;
  box-shadow: -2000px 0 0 2000px #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #434343;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-progress {
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #666;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 16px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #3f3f3f;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #3f3f3f;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 4px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='range']:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #3f3f3f;
}
input[type='range']:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #3f3f3f;
}
```

```html
<div class="audio-player">
  <audio src="https://milessite.com/music/music.mp3"></audio>
  <button class="play">play</button>
  <input
    class="seek"
    type="range"
    min="0"
    max="100"
    value="0"
    step="0.0001"
  />
</div>
<div class="audio-player">
  <audio src="https://milessite.com/music/music1.mp3"></audio>
  <button class="play">play</button>
  <input
    class="seek"
    type="range"
    min="0"
    max="100"
    value="0"
    step="0.0001"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, man, you again! It works! Thank you very, very much! <3 I don't know what I would have done without you hah ;))